# Prove the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x^y (x>0)$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Given the function $f(x,y)= x^y (x>0)$

Prove that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist

I think I would choose 2 sequences $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ such that the two limits do not agree, concluding that the limit doesn't exist. But I just found a sequence $\left(\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)\right)_{n\geq1}$ and found that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} f\left(\frac{1}n, 0\right) =1$, but I don't know how to choose the second sequence.

Can you explain or any way to prove it

Comment: What would be the most obvious choice?

Comment: See my answer to the Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange question [Multivariable limits](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1891/745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try directly construct a constant-valued sequence, e.g., ${x_n}^{y_n} = 1/2$ for all $n$.

If we set $y_n = 1 / n$, then solve for $x_n$, we will get $x_n = \sqrt[1/n]{1/2} = \dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

Then is it correct for $(x_n, y_n) \to (0, 0)$?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about construct it directly

Comment: @Amath This technique is quite standard and useful for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Choose for example  $\;x_n=\frac1n\;,\;\;y_n=\frac1{\ln n}\;$ , then both

$$\;x_n\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}0\xleftarrow[n\to\infty]\, y_n$$ but

$$f\left(x_n\,,y_n\right)=\left(\frac1n\right)^{1/{\ln n}}=\text{exp}\left({\frac1{\ln n}\ln n}\right)=e$$

which doesn't converge to $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: It should be $\displaystyle \left(\frac1n\right)^{1/{\ln n}}=\text{exp}\left({\frac1{\ln n}(-\ln n})\right)=e^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't know if it's only my computer but I can only see half of $n\to\infty$ and $m\to\infty$. May be you have to decrease the vertical distance between the arrow and $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @PinkRabbit Of course. Thanks for the catch